# C code for file downloading from internet using curl

Tags: c, curl

I saw some c codes relative to the topic. I've tried them but only I get errors saying a heap of errors of curl.h. I googled much but couldn't find a good answer. I'm using CCS C compiler version v5.008. I really want to solve this problem soon.

I tried to compile the code from the following link.

[enter link description here](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/simple.html)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>

int main(void)
{
  CURL *curl;
  CURLcode res;

  curl = curl_easy_init();
  if(curl) {
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://example.com");
    /* example.com is redirected, so we tell libcurl to follow redirection */ 
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1L);

    /* Perform the request, res will get the return code */ 
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    /* Check for errors */ 
    if(res != CURLE_OK)
      fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
              curl_easy_strerror(res));

    /* always cleanup */ 
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Gives me error: "Error 119"C:\Users\Sisitha\Documents\CCS C Projects\ Testing\curl\curlbuild.h" Line 556(145,183): " Unknown non-configure build target" "

I'm on Windows 7(64bit)

Please help me to solve this matter.
Thanks!

Comment: Have you installed the curl libraries?

Comment: Well....I'm new to this field. I put all the curl header files into the CCS "devices" folder.And I also can run curl commands using cmd.

Comment: Show us your code and your compiler errors.

Comment: It is the sample code from http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/simple.html

Comment: "Error 119"C:\Users\Sisitha\Documents\CCS C Projects\ Testing\curl\curlbuild.h" Line 556(145,183): " Unknown non-configure build target" "  This is the first error and there are 99 more :-(\

Comment: Update your question instead of posting into comments.

Comment: Sorry... learnt it just now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

curl uses GNU autotools to be built from source.  There's a library to be built and configured, for the example program and header file, to link against.  The error :

```
Error 119"C:\Users\Sisitha\Documents\CCS C Projects\ Testing\curl\curlbuild.h" Line 556(145,183): " Unknown non-configure build target"
```

Suggests that the curl.h you included, hasn't been configured, by the standard GNU `./configure; make; make install` build sequence.

Curl installation instructions [Install -- how to install curl](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/install.html)

Comment: ./configure gives an error saying '.' is nota recognized as internal or external